# Proper Sleeve size for Android Netrunner

Tags: android-netrunner, card-sleeves

I am trying to find the right sleeve size to get for Android Netrunner.

Fantasy Flight was nice enough to put a color coded sleeve and number of packs needed for that box on the back of both the core set and the expansions.

However it shows Blue sleeves for the Core set and Sliver for the expansions. 
I am trying to figure out which sleeves are the proper fit.

If you can provide a link to where I can buy them that would be great as well.

Comment: For future questions like this, there is a Geeklist on boardgamegeek dedicated to cataloguing which card sleeves are appropriate for which games. Here's Netrunner's entry: https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/164572/item/2925400#item2925400

Answer (score 7):

Android Netrunner cards are the same size as Magic: the Gathering cards, so you can use any sleeves that are Magic sized for them. This includes [Fantasy Flight](http://store.fantasyflightgames.com/showproducts.cfm?FullCat=206), [Ultra-Pro](http://www.ultrapro.com/product_list.php?cPath=70_150), [KMC](http://www.miniaturemarket.com/collectible-card-games/supplies/card-sleeves/kmc-sleeves.html), and [Dragon Shield](http://www.arcanetinmen.dk/products/dragon-shield-sleeves-standardsize-100-ct). The color or design on the sleeves doesn't matter as long as the deck has all of the same color/design (the Corporation and Runner decks can have different colors/designs if you choose, but that isn't required).

Answer (score 0):

> However it shows Blue sleeves for the Core set and Sliver for the expansions.

This may be a misprint in the physical version. However, online information consistently states that you only need Standard Card Game Sleeves ([Gray](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/fantasy-flight-supply/products/standard-card-game-sleeves/))

For reference:

- [Core Game - 6 Gray packs needed](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/android-netrunner-the-card-game/products/android-netrunner-the-card-game/)
- [Data and Destiny Deluxe Expansion - 4 Gray packs needed](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/android-netrunner-the-card-game/products/data-and-destiny/)
- [What Lies Ahead Data Pack - 2 Gray packs needed](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/android-netrunner-the-card-game/products/what-lies-ahead/)

Answer (score -3):

There are lot of [**card sleeves**](http://kmccardsleeve.com.au/) in market, but the best one is KMC card sleeves and according it provides great longevity and ultimate protection.

Comment: OP is asking which size of the cards is right, not which producer is better. Unless KMC sleeves come in only one size, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

Why not Dragon Shield clear? You will be able to see the color and design on the back of the cards. This seems good for the flip cards as well.

Comment: OP is asking which size of the cards is right, not which producer is better. Unless Dragon Shield sleeves come in only one size, this does not answer the question.